# ionic back button not taking me to the previous page when I jump from tab1's child page to tab2's child page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, navigationcontroller

I have tabs, where each tab is its own page/path.
So there exists tab1->childComponent1 and tab2-> childComponent2.
Now I performed a navigation using

```
navCtrl.navigateForward(['tab1/', 'childComponent2/'])
```

The childComponent2 has a back button.

```
<ion-back-button class="back-button" text="" defaultHref="" icon="arrow-back"></ion-back-button>
```

This takes me back to the defaultHref, which is an entirely new tab. I'm guessing it's utilizing the defaultHref because navController doesn't have an empty stack with no navigation history in it.

So what I was looking for is the following.

SCENARIO 1 - childComponent1 -> childComponent2 ... On clicking ionic-back-button here it takes me back to childComponent1

SCENARIO 2 - tab2 -> childComponent1 .. on clicking ionic-back-button here it takes me back to tab2

SCENARIO 2 Seems to be working perfectly alright at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This may not help, but I've also had trouble with ion-back-button and eventually gave up and used `this.navController.back();`

In your component

```
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';

 goBack() {
    this.navController.back();
  }
```

Then in the html

```
<ion-button (click)='goBack()'>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="chevron-back"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure navController has an empty stack with no navigation history in it. So back takes me nowhere.

Comment: @FlynSequeira how did you handle the pop back if the stack was empty? Is it possible to define a fallback?